# Check if there's a name present in json

Tags: jquery, json

I want to check if the json file has a name 'Collection' in it's content. If so do this and if not present do that. There are several JSON files present so I'll show one with the name in it and one without.

I can't figure out what the best way is to check inside my jQuery function.

JSON

```
// name collection is present //
{
  collection: {
      image: {},
      products: {
      }, //etc
   }
 }
```

JSON

```
// name collection is not present //
{
  catalog (or textpage): {
      image: {},
      content: {
      }, //etc
   }
 }
```

What i try to do is something like this:

```
function widget(catId, catHref){   
  var url = catHref;

 $.getJSON(url, function(json) {

    if (collection == true) {
      console.log('Yes products');
      // build some html
    }else {
      console.log('No sir no products');
      // build other html
    } etc...
```

I tried things like 'hasProperty' or 'TypeOf' or 'undefined' etc. But with absolutly no luck. I'm completly stuck on this. This can't be that hard?

Anyone?

Comment: you might want to try `if("collection" in json)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (json["collection"]) { ... }
```

Or

```
if (json.collection) { ... }
```

You might want to explicitly check for `undefined` and/or `null`, e.g.,

```
if (json.collection !== undefined) { ... }
```

Doing so guards against pathological JSON if it could be sent as `false`.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
if (json["collection"]) {}

if (json.collection) {}
```

or

```
if ("collection" in json) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if(YourJson.hasOwnProperty('collection')){

}
```

you can  find the details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)